# Insertar imagen en base de datos en Sql Server c# uwp

Tags: c#, sql-server, xaml, uwp

El problema que tengo es  salvar la imagen que que se encuentra en el control imagen en la tabla de la base de datos en formato Bmp. Dicha imagen que elijo desde el Explorador archivos se insertar el control imagen.  lo quiero saber es como insertar la imagen la tabla de la base de datos .

codigo  insertar imagen:

```
try
              {
                const string SqlString = "insert into PetTable(PetType,DuoDate,PetName,PetRace,PetColor,PetChip,PetGender,PetSterile) values (@petType,@duoDate,@petName,@petRace,@petColor,@petChip,@petGender,@petSterile)";

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                        {


                            cmd.CommandText = SqlString;
                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();





                           // cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", SqlDbType.Image).Value;



                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtMascota.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@duoDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateNac.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToLocalTime();
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtName.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petRace", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtRace.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petColor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = txtColor.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petChip", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtChip.Text;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petGender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = (bool)radioMale.IsChecked
                                ? radioMale.Content : radioFemale.Content;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@petSterile", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = (bool)rbesteri.IsChecked
                                ? rbesteri.Content : rbnoesteri.Content;

                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! una imagen es un archivo.. y un archivo es una cadena binaria... aunque yo no recomiendo guardar nunca un archivo en la base de datos (el sistema operativo lo hace mucho mejor), transformaste la imagen a binario? o por ahi empiezan tus problemas?

Comment: hola: como puedo insertar en la base de datos una imagen  en binario , en la class.cs tengo  **public BitmapImage Picture { get; set; }**